# Arrayformula - multiply only if the both columns have a value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have 2 columns that contain prices, and I multiple them together using the bellow arrayformula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(E4:E * D4:D)
```

I would like it to only multiply is columns E and D contain values.

How do I acheive this?

Comment: To clarify, you want to to multiply one column of prices and one column of quantities, and sum them into this formula ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(E4:E)*LEN(D4:D), E4:E * D4:D,))
```

And see if that works ?

Comment: This works however the rows that don't have values the column that holds the array formula now outputs FALSE instead of £0,00. I wanted to not have it display anything if the columns didn't have a value to tidy my sheet up rather than having one column filled with £0,00.

Comment: Did you put a comma directly after E4:E * D4:D (as per JPV's answer)?

Comment: Oh... I removed it because I thought it was a typo. Haha. Yeah it works as I want. Thank you both.